# How to flatten the columns with Series in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df,i need to flatten the series column

```
data = pd.DataFrame([['TRAN',[{'Name':'Ben','Age':'24'}],'T','Good'],
                     ['LMI',[{'Name':'Zoe','Age':'32'}],'U','Better'],
                     ['ARN',[{'Name':'Jack','Age':'28'}],'V','Best']
                     ], 
                    columns=['Type', 'Applicant', 'Decision', 'Action'])
```

data is pandas dataframe, Applicant column is a Series,

```
#data
type(data)
Out[25]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
#Applicant Column
type(data.Applicant)
Out[26]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

I need to flatten the series and convert the dataframe with column names as `'Type'`, `'Applicant.Name'`, `'Applicant.Age'`, `'Decision'`, `'Action'`.

Comment: There is always one dict in list? not possible `[{'Name':'Ben','Age':'24'}, {'Name':'A','Age':'46'}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General solution if multiple dictionaries per list - use list comprehension for add index value to new column, create `DataFrame`, add [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and last [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([['TRAN',[{'Name':'Ben','Age':'24'}, {'Name':'A','Age':'46'}],'T','Good'],
                     ['LMI',[{'Name':'Zoe','Age':'32'}],'U','Better'],
                     ['ARN',[{'Name':'Jack','Age':'28'}],'V','Best']
                     ], 
                    columns=['Type', 'Applicant', 'Decision', 'Action'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame([dict(x, **{'idx':k}) for k, v in data.pop('Applicant').items() for x in v])
                   .set_index('idx').add_prefix('Applicant.')
print (df1)
    Applicant.Age Applicant.Name
idx                             
0              24            Ben
0              46              A
1              32            Zoe
2              28           Jack

df2 = data.join(df1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
   Type Decision  Action Applicant.Age Applicant.Name
0  TRAN        T    Good            24            Ben
1  TRAN        T    Good            46              A
2   LMI        U  Better            32            Zoe
3   ARN        V    Best            28           Jack
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution without `apply` (if performance matters) would be:

```
data=(pd.DataFrame(data.pop('Applicant').str[0].values.tolist())
                              .add_prefix('Applicant.').join(data))
```

---

```
  Applicant.Age Applicant.Name  Type Decision  Action
0            24            Ben  TRAN        T    Good
1            32            Zoe   LMI        U  Better
2            28           Jack   ARN        V    Best
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `pd.concat` and an `apply(pd.Series)` as well as an `add_prefix`:

```
>>> pd.concat([data, data.pop('Applicant').str[0].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('Applicant.')], axis=1)
   Type Decision  Action Applicant.Age Applicant.Name
0  TRAN        T    Good            24            Ben
1   LMI        U  Better            32            Zoe
2   ARN        V    Best            28           Jack
>>>
```

I concatenate `data` with my `DataFrame` with the edited values.